# Importing CSV (with <br />) to Excel issue

Tags: excel

I'm having problem importing a csv file with <br /> contents in it to excel. It includes the data after the <br /> tag to another column which it seems the <br /> tag becomes a delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm, I just wrote a php script to handle that.